# JavaScript Variable Method ( Two Lines)

Tags: javascript, variables

I know different ways to give a title to variables in java, but I remember a way where you could put the the variables on one line (a, b, c, ect.), but put the variable solutions on another line (1, 2, 3, ect.). Does anyone know this method, and could you please tell me it.

Comment: How do you do this in Java? I can't think of a way.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with destructuring, but it looks a bit confusing IMO:

```js
const [
  a, b, c, d
] = [
  1, 2, 3, 'etc'
];

console.log(a);
console.log(d);
```

The way it works is, when you have an iterable on the right-hand side of an `=`, and a list of comma-separated identifiers inside of `[]`s on the right-hand side, each element from the iterable gets put into the associated new identifier of the same index. So, above, `1` goes into `a` because both `a` and `1` come first in the list.

(Arrays are iterable; `[1, 2, 3, 'etc']` is an array.)

If you have a situation where you have multiple variables that are similar enough to be declared at once like this, consider using an object instead, rather than lots of standalone variables:

```js
const options = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 'etc'
};

console.log(options.a);
console.log(options.d);
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question a little bit for more explanation about that behavior?